# DCOS: not able to start any service is always shows deploying

Tags: dcos

Enviornment :

DCOS : 1.7 running on vagrant

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons this could fail, but you did not provide enough information to narrow it down.  However, the most common problem observed when getting started is missing the bit about having a private vs public agent available and the role being specified in the app json.  I can't tell from the single screen shot what environment you are running or the json for the apps you were trying to run.  If you are really stuck, try visiting https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/custom/troubleshooting/ and check out their slack channel for assistance. https://dcos-community.slack.com/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when installing DCOS form the Azure template, when I logged in, it appeared that I had 0 nodes connected in my cluster (which is obviously not good). I reinstalled it from another template and it fixed my problem. Hope it helps.